# Renaming and moving files while in a loop in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

So I want to be able to drag one or more rar or zip files to a batch .cmd script that extracts the file with 7zip to a directory one level up, renames the extracted file to the current folder name and then deletes the folder with the rar or zip archives.

So far I have:

```
set work=%temp%\%random%%random%%random%%random%
mkdir "%work%" || goto :eof

for %%A in (*.zip *.rar) do (
    "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"%work%" "%%~A"
    for %%F in ("%work%\*") do move "%%~F" "%%~nA%%~xF"
)

rmdir "%work%"
```

And that extracts the file to the current directory and renames it to the archive name but I want to name it to the directory the archive is in so %%~nA needs to be changed but typing "for /?" doesn't seem to give me an option to get the current directory. Then I need to move the extracted file one level up and delete the folder with the archive files, I just don't know how to reference the files when using move and rmdir when in a loop.

This is my first attempt at batch scripting please go easy on me.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you are describing and I'm thinking a view from above might be better than getting into code details. You have zip/rar files somewhere, it looks like you are dragging them into the same folder were the Batch file is - is that correct? Are the ones in the same folder as the batch file the original zip/rar files, or are they copies?  Batch can run without concerns for errors, so if your unzip fails and the script deletes the originals, what then?  I'm thinking you want the final unzipped files in a subfolder where the batch file is - correct?

Comment: The current directory is contained in `%cd%`. To get the current leafname to a metavariable, use `for /f %%L in ("%cd%") do echo leafname is %%~nxL`.  The current directory is also `.` and the parent `..` so you could also use `FOR %%L IN (.) DO ECHO Leafname is %%~nxL` and `FOR %%L IN (..) DO ECHO Parent is %%~nxL` Do remember that you cannot have a file and a subdirectory named **exactly** the same, so you would need to preserve the extension name when you change the filename part.

Comment: So I have the batch file in a folder c:/archive/ with a rar in a sub folder ie c:/archive/volume1/data.rar I want to drag the rar from the sub folder to the batch script. Then have the script name the file that comes out of the rar after the sub folder name (volume1), keep the file extension, and put the file one level up (c:/archive/) . Then delete the folder c:/archive/volume1/ and everything in it. I am pulling these volume folders from a FTP so if one fails I can just re-download, it doesn't take very long.

Comment: @Endzo, thank you so much for the explanation.  That really helps me understand. Is there only one zip/rar file in each subfolder volume1,volume2,etc...?  If so, I would like to suggest a different approach.  Drag folder(s) on top of batch file.  The batch will run and we use SHIFT to work on each folder.  This gives the batch the folder name for renaming the file to later, it also gives batch the folder to find the zip/rar file in.  Unzip the file into "c:\archive\volumeN\Extract", rename it there, move it to c:\archive\, and then delete volumeN folder along with everything in it.

Comment: @Darin, Oh yeah that sounds better because I often get 2-5 of these folders at once to process. There is only one zip or rar in each folder and sometimes the rar is a multi part archive but my current script seems to handle those fine. There is usually only one file in each rar but I was putting it in a loop to handle multiple files in each rar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be more of a lesson on how to do reasonably good programing in *cough* a bad *cough* the batch programming language.

The first stage is to work from the outside inwards, or top down.  It only took a few minutes to build this framework.  The sub goals/steps are:

1. Simply loop through all of the parameters and see if we can save them to a variable and then echo them out.
2. Figure out how to extract the SubFolderName (This will later be the file name), and echo it per each loop.
3. Build the Extract folder and echo per each loop.
4. Realize you forgot you were going to need the folder path of the calling batch file, add it as first parameter, and extract it before entering the :ltpLoop.

The %1 gets the first parameter, while SHIFT will shift all parameters so that %1=%2, %2=%3, %3=%4, %4=%5, etc...  This effectively removes the first parameter and reduces the total number of parameters by 1.  The IF statement exits the script when SHIFT has removed all parameters and %1 no longer has a value.

Also, a lot of people will follow the ECHO command with a period (ECHO.Text to echo), but I had one bad case where period printed a blank line instead of the text, but semicolon ; was fine - so I no do period, period!

```
@ECHO OFF
    GOTO :Start

:LoopThroughParameters
    SET CmdPath=%~1
    SHIFT
    ECHO;[[[%CmdPath%]]]
:ltpLoop
    IF [%1] EQU [] GOTO :EOF
    SET Folder=%~1
    SET SubFolderName=%~nx1
    SET ExtractFolder=%~1\Extract

    ECHO;
    ECHO;[%Folder%]
    ECHO;[%SubFolderName%]
    ECHO;[%ExtractFolder%]
    SHIFT
    GOTO :ltpLoop

:Start
    CALL :LoopThroughParameters "%~dp0" %*
PAUSE
```

In stage 2 we start by cleaning up the code by removing the unneeded echos.

```
:LoopThroughParameters
    SET CmdPath=%~1
    SHIFT

:ltpLoop
    IF [%1] EQU [] GOTO :EOF
    SET Folder=%~1
    SET SubFolderName=%~nx1
    SET ExtractFolder=%~1\Extract
    <<New Code Will Go Here>>
    SHIFT
    GOTO :ltpLoop
```

Start experimenting in the <<New Code Will Go Here>> area.

```
    ECHO;FOR %%C IN ("%Folder%\*.zip" "%Folder%\*.rar") DO (
```

The code is tested by creating 5 folders, with one zip file in each folder, and dragging the folders on to the batch file and seeing if we like the commands it built.

```
FOR %C IN ("D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume5\*.zip" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume5\*.rar") DO (
FOR %C IN ("D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume1\*.zip" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume1\*.rar") DO (
FOR %C IN ("D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume2\*.zip" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume2\*.rar") DO (
FOR %C IN ("D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume3\*.zip" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume3\*.rar") DO (
FOR %C IN ("D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume4\*.zip" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume4\*.rar") DO (
```

Then we try to build the extraction commands:

```
    FOR %%C IN ("%Folder%\*.zip" "%Folder%\*.rar") DO (
        ECHO;"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"%ExtractFolder%" "%%~C"
    )
```

Check if results look correct:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume5\Extract" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume5\Last Zip file.zip"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume1\Extract" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume1\SomeZipFile.zip"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume2\Extract" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume2\JustAnotherZip.zip"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume3\Extract" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume3\YetAnotherZip.zip"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume4\Extract" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume4\How Many Zips Was This.zip"
```

In stage 3 we try it for real - remove the echo:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"%ExtractFolder%" "%%~C"
```

Check if we like the results (You can see I'm using some old latitude-e5440 PDFs I happen to find in a forgotten folder someplace):

```
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433>dir /s /b
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\DragDropAndExtract.CMD
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume1
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume2
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume3
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume4
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume5
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume1\Extract
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume1\SomeZipFile.zip
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume1\Extract\lat_e_reimage_guide_en-us.pdf
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume2\Extract
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume2\JustAnotherZip.zip
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume2\Extract\latitude-e5440-laptop_owners-manual_en-us.pdf
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume3\Extract
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume3\YetAnotherZip.zip
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume3\Extract\latitude-e5440-laptop_user's guide_en-us.pdf
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume4\Extract
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume4\How Many Zips Was This.zip
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume4\Extract\latitude-e5440-laptop_users-guide_en-us.pdf
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume5\Extract
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume5\Last Zip file.zip
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume5\Extract\latitude-e5440-laptop_white papers_en-us.pdf
```

For stage 4 we echo both the extract command and xcopy command to see what they look like:

```
        ECHO;"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"%ExtractFolder%" "%%~C"
        ECHO; XCOPY /V /C /Y "%ExtractFolder%\*.*" "%CmdPath%\%SubFolderName%.*"
```

Just a reminder, every test is done by dragging the 5 folders onto the batch file:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume5\Extract" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume5\Last Zip file.zip"
XCOPY /V /C /Y "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume5\Extract\*.*" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\\volume5.*"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume1\Extract" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume1\SomeZipFile.zip"
XCOPY /V /C /Y "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume1\Extract\*.*" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\\volume1.*"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume2\Extract" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume2\JustAnotherZip.zip"
XCOPY /V /C /Y "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume2\Extract\*.*" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\\volume2.*"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume3\Extract" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume3\YetAnotherZip.zip"
XCOPY /V /C /Y "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume3\Extract\*.*" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\\volume3.*"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume4\Extract" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume4\How Many Zips Was This.zip"
XCOPY /V /C /Y "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume4\Extract\*.*" "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\\volume4.*"
```

Stage 5, try it live:

```
        "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"%ExtractFolder%" "%%~C"
        XCOPY /V /C /Y "%ExtractFolder%\*.*" "%CmdPath%\%SubFolderName%.*"
```

What did we get?:

```
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433>dir /s/b
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume1
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume1.pdf
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume2
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume2.pdf
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume3
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume3.pdf
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume4
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume4.pdf
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume5
D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume5.pdf
```

Stage 6, what will remove directory look like? (Decided to hide the other commands with REM)

```
        REM "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"%ExtractFolder%" "%%~C"
        REM XCOPY /V /C /Y "%ExtractFolder%\*.*" "%CmdPath%\%SubFolderName%.*"
        ECHO;RD /Q /S "%Folder%"
```

And we have:

```
RD /Q /S "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume5"
RD /Q /S "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume1"
RD /Q /S "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume2"
RD /Q /S "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume3"
RD /Q /S "D:\Temp\StackOverflow\71345433\volume4"
```

Stage 7 is the final code and tests:

```
@ECHO OFF
    GOTO :Start

:LoopThroughParameters
    SET CmdPath=%~1
    SHIFT

:ltpLoop
    IF [%1] EQU [] GOTO :EOF
    SET Folder=%~1
    SET SubFolderName=%~nx1
    SET ExtractFolder=%~1\Extract
    
    FOR %%C IN ("%Folder%\*.zip" "%Folder%\*.rar") DO (
        "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"%ExtractFolder%" "%%~C"
        XCOPY /V /C /Y "%ExtractFolder%\*.*" "%CmdPath%\%SubFolderName%.*"
        RD /Q /S "%Folder%"
    )

    SHIFT
    GOTO :ltpLoop

:Start
    CALL :LoopThroughParameters "%~dp0" %*
PAUSE
```

All folders were deleted when done.

Now, let's do something experimental.  I've never seen this fail, but I haven't used it that often.  Let's give it a try:

```
@ECHO OFF
    GOTO :Start

:LoopThroughParameters
    SET CmdPath=%~1
    SHIFT

:ltpLoop
    IF [%1] EQU [] GOTO :EOF
    SET Folder=%~1
    SET SubFolderName=%~nx1
    SET ExtractFolder=%~1\Extract
    
    FOR %%C IN ("%Folder%\*.zip" "%Folder%\*.rar") DO (
        ( 
            "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"%ExtractFolder%" "%%~C" 
        ) && (
            XCOPY /V /C /Y "%ExtractFolder%\*.*" "%CmdPath%\%SubFolderName%.*"
        ) && (
            RD /Q /S "%Folder%"
        ) || (
            PowerShell Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "Error:"
            PAUSE
        )
    )

    SHIFT
    GOTO :ltpLoop

:Start
    CALL :LoopThroughParameters "%~dp0" %*
```

If any of the commands separated by && fail, then execution jumps to the command prefixed by ||.  But if all of the commands separated by && succeed without throwing an error code, then the command prefixed by || is skipped.  In theory, this will prevent the folder from being deleted, and pause the code, if there is problem.

So, we re-created the folders, and then used HxD to the damage zip file in volume4 folder.
[image: HxD making a PDF Bad]

It worked perfectly!  Folder volume4 was not deleted.  Tried the test again, this time damaging the PDF in folder volume2, worked perfectly!

As you can tell, I can do things in Batch that many can't do in PowerShell, and yes @Olaf, that's not necessarily something to be proud of! ;)

Comment: Wow this is amazing, It really helped me understand the intricacies of this problem. The help with the steps that you took to get the answer are great. And then you threw in error checking on the end. Nice job!

Comment: @Endzo, there is still at least one thing I forgot, we probably want the program limited to deleting only those folders in the same place as the batch file.  The odds of you accidently grabbing a folder and dropping it on the batch file is extremely slim, but good programming would  be probably prevent that accident from happening.  I just failed to think about it until late last night.  I will probably add an edit at the end with a fix for that.  Also, anything you want different, or issue you can think of, let me know and I will try to put that in with the edit.

Comment: I have tested it with many different folders of zip and rar archives and it works exactly as expected. I was also able to modify it to do another task now that I understand how it works and how to more effectively troubleshoot.