# PowerShell :if else

Tags: powershell

m new to batch scripts and powershell
is there a way to use if else on this script to check if ok do something if error do something else:

```
PS C:\Users\Amine>
>> Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "*LuminonCore IDDCX*" | ft -wrap -autosize Status

Status
------
OK

//after disabling the driver


PS C:\Users\Amine>
>> Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "*LuminonCore IDDCX*" | ft -wrap -autosize Status

Status
------
Error
```

[image: powershell]

Comment: For batch files, look near the bottom of this answer for code with lines containing `) && (` and `) || (` in them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71358755/4190564

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Grouping Operator `( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#grouping-operator--) to wrap the expression, doing so allows you to reference the **Value** of the `Status` property of the returned object, then you can use [`-eq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#equality-operators) for equality evaluation:

```sh
if((Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "*LuminonCore IDDCX*").Status -eq 'ok') {
    # ok here, do something
}
else {
    # error here, do something
}
```

The example above assumes there would be only **one object** returned by `Get-PnpDevice`, however since you're using wildcards (`*`), opens up the possibility to more than one result, in which case you would need to [loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2) over each returned object:

```sh
foreach($device in Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "*LuminonCore IDDCX*") {
    if($device.Status -eq 'ok') {
        # ok here
    }
    else {
        # fail here
    }
}
```